# Subsetting column and select next n rows based on value in the same column

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a column in a data frame that I would like to subset based on a header in the same column. It essentially looks something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(col = c("Var: A", "1", "3", "5", "Var:B", "2", "4", "6", "7", "Var: C", "7", "1"))

[df]
      col
1  Var: A
2       1
3       3
4       5
5   Var:B
6       2
7       4
8       6
9       7
10 Var: C
11      7
12      1
```

What I want to do is to subset this column based on the different 'Var' headings, to end up with this:

```
[1] Var: A
         1
         3
         5
[2] Var: B
         2
         4
         6
         7
```

And finally to store them in different variables.

I have looked at examples explaining how to select n rows before or after a specific value in a column, but unfortunately most of the variables I want to extract are of different length so that won't work. Is there any way this can be done in a relatively straightforward way?

Comment: @Sotos Thanks! That worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `grepl` to find the `Vars` and split, i.e.

```
split(df, cumsum(grepl('Var', df$col)))
```

which gives,

> ```
> $`1`
>      col
> 1 Var: A
> 2      1
> 3      3
> 4      5
>
> $`2`
>     col
> 5 Var:B
> 6     2
> 7     4
> 8     6
> 9     7
>
> $`3`
>       col
> 10 Var: C
> 11      7
> 12      1
> ```